# Limit string length within a set?

Tags: c++, set, string-length

I have to write a program that allows the user to input **up to 20 names** of **up to 40 characters each**.

When I write the code without trying to limit the string lengths in any way, it works. But when I try to limit string length with an if/else statement, it doesn't work. I'm pretty new to C++ so it was really a shot in the dark. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(const string& name) {
    cout << name << endl;
}

int main() {
    set<string> ListOfNames;
    cout << "Please enter up to 20 names of up to 40 characters each below:     " << endl;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
    string name;
    cout << i << ". ";
    getline(cin, name);
    if (name.size() >= 40) {
        ListOfNames.insert(name);
    }
    else break;
    cerr << "You entered more than 40 characters. Please try again.";
}

for_each(ListOfNames.begin(), ListOfNames.end(), &print);
return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
1. (user inputs name here)
press any key to continue...
```

**EDITED CODE**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(const string& name) {
    cout << name << endl;
}

int main() {
    set<string> ListOfNames;
    cout << "Please enter up to 20 names of up to 40 characters each below:         " << endl;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
    string name;
    cout << i << ". ";
    getline(cin, name);
    if (name.size() <= 40) {
        ListOfNames.insert(name);
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "You entered more than 40 characters. Please try again.";
        break;
    }

    for_each(ListOfNames.begin(), ListOfNames.end(), &print);
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside if change the condition to name.size() >= 40

and in else break after crr and both th statement should be inside a {}

```
if (name.size() <= 40) {
    ListOfNames.insert(name);
}
else
{
    cerr << "You entered more than 40 characters. Please try again.";
    break;
}
```

Comment: When I do this, it only allows me to input 1 name, not all 20.
For example:
Input: 1. Max
Output: Max

Comment: you forgot to close the bracket of the for loop. close the the for loop after closing else and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you said to only run the code if the string is greater than 40 not less than 40

Answer (score 1):

Write a separate function to get and validate the input. In that function, check that the input is less than 40 characters long, and refuse to accept it if it isn't:

```
std::string get_limited_string(std::string prompt, int max = 40) {
    std::string input;
    do {
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
    } while (input.size() >= max);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Call it from the loop that gathers the 20 input strings.